# jQuery `.click()` not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble getting the function inside `.click()` to execute fully. If I put `alert("Hello");` before the block it give the alert but the rest won't execute...

I want that when I click a div `#loginPopTrigger` another div `#loginpop` fades in. Then if I click `#loginpop` or `#closelogin`, `#loginpop` fades out.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I have right now:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>MainFrame</title>

    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Java.js"></script>

    <link href="stylesheets/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="HeaderContainer">        
        <div id="loginPopTrigger">
            <li>Login</li>
        </div>
    </div>        

    <div id="loginPop">
        <div id="closelogin">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div id="loginContainer">
            <div id="title">
                <div id="logologin"></div>...
            </div>

            <paper-input label="Email Address or ID" floatinglabel></paper-input>
            <paper-input type="password" label="Password" floatinglabel></paper-input>

            <div id="forgot">Forgot?</div>
            <div id="LoginPageOptions">
                <paper-checkbox id="staylogged">Stay Logged On</paper-checkbox>
                <div id="googlelogin">Login with Google+</div>
            </div>
            <div id="LoginPageButtons">
                <paper-button id="loginButton" raised>Login</paper-button>
                <paper-button id="signupbutton" raised>Sign Up</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /*-----------------------------------------  BASIC  --------------------------------------*/
@font-face {
    font-family: main;
    src: url(Fonts/MGNORMAL.TTF);
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

/*-----------------------------------------  HEADER  --------------------------------------*/

#HeaderContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 5%;
    top: 2.5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
}

#loginPopTrigger {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: main;
    font-size: 20;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18;
    left: 90%;
    top: 28%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#loginPopTrigger:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

/*-----------------------------------------  LOGIN POPUP  --------------------------------------*/

#loginpop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#loginContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    height: 20%;
    left: 42%;
    top: 35%;
    font-family: main;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}

#title{
    font-size: 35;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#forgot {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: #2a2a2a;
    font-size: 14;
    top: 129;
    left: 80%;
}

#LoginPageOptions{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:;
}

#staylogged {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    --paper-checkbox-checked-color: var(--paper-black-500);
    --paper-checkbox-checked-ink-color: var(--paper-black-500);
}

#googlelogin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#LoginPageButtons{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#loginButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff; 
}

#signupbutton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
}

/*--  CLOSE LOGIN POPUP  --*/
#closelogin {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2.6%;
    left: 97%;
    cursor: pointer;
}   

#closelogin span {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20;
    background: #000;
    margin: 24%;
}

#closelogin span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

#closelogin span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginPopTrigger').click(function () {
        alert("Hello"); //This executes
        $('#loginpop').fadeToggle(); //This does not
    });

    $("#closelogin").click(function () {
        $('#loginpop').fadeToggle();
    });

    $("#loginpop").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: what is webcomponents.js?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: id loginPop != loginpop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` is wrong:

```
$('#loginPopTrigger').click(function () {
    $('#loginPop').fadeToggle(); //This does not
});

$("#closelogin").click(function () {
    $('#loginPop').fadeToggle();
});


$("#loginPop").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
});
```

**Shorter way**

```
$('#loginPopTrigger, #closelogin, #loginPop').click(function () {
    $('#loginPop').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! But what do you mean by the `id` is wrong? Just so I can avoid the error in the future.

Comment: you forgot the capital p in loginPop

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of scripts like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/Java.js"></script>
```

Because if any of the function in `webcomponents.js` uses jquery, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong ID (you forgot the camel case). Also, you should use on() method instead of click() :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loginPopTrigger').on('click',function () {
    $('#loginPop').fadeToggle(); //This does not
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ids are not the same. In the html it's `loginPop` and in js it's `loginpop`. They are case sensitive so sometimes it's easy to miss. Check out the jsfiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/c6ojsb6c/1/